# PHP Threads and Synchronization

Tags: php, multithreading, singleton, synchronize, double-checked-locking

I'm new to PHP, so to get started I've decided to implement a singleton.

While I am able to recreate the singleton pattern in php, but I am not sure how to implement double-checked locking.

Is that even possible/needed in PHP.  I have read somewhere that PHP is not multithreaded?  Can someone confirm that?

If it is multithreaded, can someone explain to me how lock() or synchronize() work in PHP?

Thanks,
Henry

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Share-nothing Architecture

> PHP has a [Share-nothing
>   Architecture](http://talks.php.net/show/lt2004-lamp/3):
>
> - Like HTTP, each request is distinct
> - Shared data is pushed down to the data-store layer
> - Avoid front controllers
>
> This gives us:
>
> - Ability to load balance
> - Invisible failover from one datacenter to another
> - Better modularization of applications
> - Easier to develop and debug

### double-checked locking

> but I am not sure how to implement
>   double-checked locking.

In general the database layer is responsible for this. MySQL(innodb) standard has for example row level [locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)(which should be sufficient for this).

> InnoDB does locking on the row level
>   and runs queries as nonlocking
>   consistent reads by default, in the
>   style of Oracle.

If this is not sufficient than SQL also has for example [transactions](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm) to make this happen.

> Books Online defines a transaction as
>   a "sequence of operations performed as
>   a single logical unit of work"

### Fork processes

Like the slides say PHP has a Share-nothing-Architecture(traditional) which also does imply that PHP does NOT have a [thread(model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading). Although you can compile([not enabled by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php)) PHP to have support to [fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) processes which can communicate with each other. When you also compile the [Semaphore Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php) then you can do things like [sem_acquire](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php) and [sem_release](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-release.php). But in general this does not apply PHP.

Comment: PHP does have threading, for relevant information you should follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading