# How implement synchronized class PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have ran into some issue during creating client to the [Google Fusion Tables](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html). Google Fusion Tables has restriction to request. It allow a maximum of 5 requests per second to the Google Fusion Tables server.

How can i implement or create client class which control requests count per second in PHP?

Comment: I would have a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549742/synchronized-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I would store your last X request times in a database table and use that to track if you are hitting your limit.